# Radio Submit Button Form and Redirect

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I am wanting to redirect to another page but at the same time being able to grab the details of the button that was selected. I was reading up on how [onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) works with HTML and [radio buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) work. Prior to adding buttons, I had a button and whenever it was clicked it would redirect me to the next page. I still want to do the same thing, just being able to add radio buttons to the view and submit that radio button so that way I can grab the information from the button that was selected.

I attempted:

```
@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Customer</h2>

<form method="POST">
<input type="radio" value="1" /><label>Valid</label>
<input type="radio" value="2" /><label>Wrong</label>
<input type="radio" value="3" /><label>InValid</label>
<a href="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("SecIndex", "Second") + "'");">
    <input type="submit" value="Address Validation" />
</a>
```

However, this does not redirect me to the page that I needed it to redirect to. I also noticed that once I select buttons I cannot unselect, is that apart of the radio button feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also noticed that once I select buttons I cannot unselect, is that apart of the radio button feature

Yes. That's how it works.

> I still want to do the same thing, just being able to add radio buttons to the view and submit that radio button so that way I can
> grab the information from the button that was selected.

If you want to post the selected value to backend, you could set `name` for radio buttons. Because model binding system will bind value by name.

View:

```
<form method="POST" asp-action="SecIndex" asp-controller="Second">     
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="Status"/><label>Valid</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="Status"/><label>Wrong</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="Status"/><label>InValid</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Address Validation" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public class SecondController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SecIndex(string Status) 
       // you can get "1" or "2" or "3" which based on your checked radio button
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that feature with me wasn't sure about that. Perfect this is good to know, will implement your suggestion thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have store capability. you can't grab data without a programming language. But you can click to redirect to another page.
Use the button tag and use the anchor tag in the button, rather than -